# Add headers when generating encoded JWT token

Tags: java, spring-security, jwt

I have below code to generate JWT token.

```
public TestTokenGenerator() {
        try {
            if (signer == null) {
                KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
                byte[] keySpecBytes = Base64.decodeBase64(getKey());
                PKCS8EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(keySpecBytes);
                PrivateKey privateKey = keyFactory.generatePrivate(keySpec);
                signer = new RsaSigner((RSAPrivateKey) privateKey, "SHA512withRSA");
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestTokenGenerator gen = new TestTokenGenerator();
        gen.customerJwt("MYUSER");  
    }

    public String customerJwt(String userCode) {
        String token = jwt(userCode, "wd.idp.ext.abc.com");
        return token;
    }

    private String jwt(String userCode, String iss) {

        Map<String, Object> claims = new HashMap<>();
        claims.put("user_name", userCode);
        claims.put("sub", userCode);
        claims.put("amr", "[aht]");

        String jwt = JwtHelper.encode(OBJECT_MAPPER.formatMap(claims), signer).getEncoded();

        log.info("User: {}, Token: {}, Claims: {}", userCode, jwt, claims);
        return jwt;
    }

    private String getKey() {
        return "WEQRwIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCBKkwggSlAgEAAoIBAQCJ2sTFNuBVzhey"
    }
```

How can I add header (e.g "kid": "b0ec688af03dd7875116bf6d36c3584256ieirir") to the above token.

Above code missing `kid` in the token header as shown below

[image: decided token]

Comment: I use https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.jsonwebtoken/jjwt/0.9.1 and there is no problem in adding custom headers. would that help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to add the token header with below additional two lines.

```
Map<String, String> headers = ImmutableMap.of("kid", 
                 "b0ec688af03dd7875116bf6d36c3584256ieirir");

String jwt = JwtHelper.encode(OBJECT_MAPPER.formatMap(claims), signer, 
        headers).getEncoded();
```

**Complete Code:**

```
public TestTokenGenerator() {
        try {
            if (signer == null) {
                KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
                byte[] keySpecBytes = Base64.decodeBase64(getKey());
                PKCS8EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(keySpecBytes);
                PrivateKey privateKey = keyFactory.generatePrivate(keySpec);
                signer = new RsaSigner((RSAPrivateKey) privateKey, "SHA512withRSA");
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestTokenGenerator gen = new TestTokenGenerator();
        gen.customerJwt("MYUSER");  
    }

    public String customerJwt(String userCode) {
        String token = jwt(userCode, "wd.idp.ext.abc.com");
        return token;
    }

    private String jwt(String userCode, String iss) {

        Map<String, Object> claims = new HashMap<>();
        Map<String, String> headers = ImmutableMap.of("kid", 
             "b0ec688af03dd7875116bf6d36c3584256ieirir");   >>>>>> New Line >>>>>>>
        claims.put("user_name", userCode);
        claims.put("sub", userCode);
        claims.put("amr", "[aht]");

        String jwt = JwtHelper.encode(OBJECT_MAPPER.formatMap(claims), signer, 
        headers).getEncoded();    >>>>>> New Line >>>>>>>>>>>>>>

        log.info("User: {}, Token: {}, Claims: {}", userCode, jwt, claims);
        return jwt;
    }

    private String getKey() {
        return "WEQRwIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCBKkwggSlAgEAAoIBAQCJ2sTFNuBVzhey"
    }
```